# Docx4j hash and salt

Tags: java, docx4j

So i look for simple answer, how to generate hash and salt for word protection option with docx4j library?

I got this method :

```
public static void setUpReadOnlyDocumentWithPassword(DocumentSettingsPart documentSettingsPart, String password) {
    final CTSettings settings = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTSettings();
    final CTDocProtect protection = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTDocProtect();
    protection.setEdit(STDocProtect.READ_ONLY);
    protection.setFormatting(true);
    protection.setEnforcement(true);
    protection.setCryptProviderType(STCryptProv.RSA_FULL);
    protection.setCryptAlgorithmClass(STAlgClass.HASH);
    protection.setCryptAlgorithmType(STAlgType.TYPE_ANY);
    protection.setCryptAlgorithmSid(new BigInteger("4"));
    protection.setCryptSpinCount(new BigInteger("100000"));
    protection.setHash(?????);
    protection.setSalt(?????);
    settings.setDocumentProtection(protection);
    documentSettingsPart.setJaxbElement(settings);
}
```

I really try everything, even translate C# code from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/63588f50-354f-43ba-b080-e0e6c51a0fb5/hash-and-saltdocumentprotection .
I want to full automate setting password to docx files.

Comment: Are you looking for comparison of files? I have same issue! 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411678/docx4j-giving-wrong-result

Comment: So what went wrong when you translated the C# code?  Maybe you should add that code to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

These days, see https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/parts/WordprocessingML/DocumentSettingsPart.java#L333

Usually this is driven by https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/packages/ProtectDocument.java